# set VM IP address to be the same every time from DHCP on CentOS 5.6

Tags: centos, ip, dhcp

I have an issue where, each time I start my CentOS 5.6 VM, DHCP (I believe) is allocating my VM a different IP. I have the VM mapped as a Samba share in Windows 7 and this changes between 192.168.0.8, 192.168.0.9 and 192.168.0.10 each time meaning I have to mount a new drive in Windows each time.

This is also frustrating as I have to update my hosts file to point to a different IP each time and any projects I have pointing to the Samba share in my IDE are also gone.

Is there a way that I can set the IP to be the same each time in the Devernet Configuration under the `setup` tool in CentOS?

```
[root@dev ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:f2:9f:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.8/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
```

Here is a screenshot of the Devernet Configuration under the `setup` utility in CentOS. I had Use DHCP *on*, but I have turned it off in this screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve this issue: move to a static IP address and related configuration for the server completely outside of the DHCP server's domains (you'll have to configure the IP address, netmask, DNS server(s), etc., on the host in question), *or* tell the DHCP server to always assign the same IP address for this particular interface.

Most DHCP server implementations support assigning a host (actually a network interface) a specific IP address, which will be handed out whenever that NIC requests an IP address without increasing the risk of collisions (since it's still the DHCP server handling the assignment). This is the route I would suggest that you take.

However, exactly how to do that depends on which DHCP server you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, am I correct in thinking I can set the specific IP address from within the `setup` > Devernet Config utility in CentOS? Does the IP have to be within a certain range? If so, how can I determine what that range is?

Comment: It depends on which approach you want to take. Static IP addresses are set on each host. Fixed, DHCP-assigned IP addresses are set in/on the DHCP server. If you give the host a fixed IP address through the DHCP server, you don't need to worry about which ranges are applicable. If you set a static IP address for one host but keep using DHCP elsewhere, that static IP address must be coordinated with the DHCP server to avoid collisions. Either way, the DHCP server is involved (unless you move to all static IPs).

Comment: A static IP is fine for me, Michael. I am having some trouble with the configuration though. As I say, DHCP on my router is rotating me between 192.168.0.8, 9 and 10...so can I set it to 192.168.0.54 (like in my screenshot) to safe collisions? What should my `Default gateway IP` be as there's limited documentation out there for this utility.

Comment: If you are happy with a static IP configured on the host, then you can simply copy the current settings. The `/24` after the IP address in the `ip a` output means you are using a 24-bit netmask, so the netmask is `255.255.255.0`. For the default route, try `route -n | grep ^0.0.0.0`; the IP address in the second field of the single line output is your default gateway. Whether this will be collision-safe is anyone's guess without -- again -- a look at the DHCP server settings.

Comment: Fanstastic! Thanks a lot. I've done a `ifdown` and `ifup` and mapped a new drive for 192.168.0.54 and it seems to be working fine. I'm just going to restart the VM and the machine itself to see if it connects OK after a restart and doesn't try and go through DHCP again.

Comment: I can confirm a restart of both the VM and the host machine works well.